# How do I undermine powers?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I want to work on claiming a system for my own power that is already owned by a different power. How do I remove that power? Specifically I am aligned with Arissa and want to take a system from Torval.

Comment: The power screen has instructions on how to undermine an opposing power on the "Control" tab.Althought undermine doesn't have direct 'take over' effect, it just raises the maintenance cost so the power will have shorter in CC budget and may give up on _some_ system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mechanics for Control systems to be lost (leaving them open for another power to acquire them), but **you can't specifically target the specific system you're after**.

If a power's Command Capital (CC) overhead/upkeep exceeds their CC income, then some of their Control systems will fall into Turmoil in the next cycle. From what I can tell, Turmoil is similar to Expansion, and if the power fails to secure the Turmoil systems, they will lose those systems, and those systems (and systems within their Exploitation radius) become available for other powers to Prepare, Expand, etc. The number of Control systems that fall into Turmoil is based on the CC upkeep cost of those systems and the total CC shortfall.

I believe if you can get the power into Turmoil, and the system you're after goes into the Turmoil state, you can undermine that system to assist it in being the one that gets freed up. However, **you can't influence which of their systems go into Turmoil**.

Things you can do to increase the CC overhead of Torval:

- Direct undermining, up to the 100% undermine trigger threshold (check the info for that system in Torval's Control system list in the Galactic Powers stuff, or the Powers Contact in a station in that system):

  - If you're pledged to an Empire power: stealing the "Torval Political Prisoners" cargo from Torval's "Private Security Ships" in Torval's control systems. (shoot cargo hatch, use limpets, whatever it takes, scoop them up, and deliver to the closest of your power's control systems)
  - If you're pledged to a non-Empire power: destroy the Torval-pledged NPC "Private Security Ships" in a Torval Control system.
- Work to change Torval's Control systems away from Feudal, Dictatorship, Communist or Co-operative rule, preferably to Democracy rule. Do this by picking a local faction that's worse for Torval and doing bulletin board missions for them, fighting for them in their wars, etc. Do not trade or turn in bounties unless your chosen local faction controls the station. I believe doing the same for Exploited systems would make a difference, but doesn't anymore.
- [Fifth column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_column) Torval by pledging to Torval and supporting Preparation and Expansion of systems that will cost Torval more CC overhead than they earn in CC income, that are easier for other powers to Undermine than for Torval to Fortify (close to Control systems of multiple other powers, and far from Torval's HQ of Synteini), or are otherwise a bad strategic move for Torval. This will work best if you can find systems that are extra easy to prepare and/or look desirable in some other way (part of a really great trade route, etc). Since Torval's "strong against" and "weak against" faction types lists are very different in Expansion and Control, it might be possible to exploit how the math about income/costs is displayed: maybe target a Control system that's under Corporate control but looks like it would be easy to flip to Democracy control.

All of those methods will work better if you check the Frontier forums, the appropriate subreddits and/or any other relevant sites, to see what other player groups are doing to undermine Torval and to see what Torval's own people are saying.

If you can undermine Torval sufficiently without Torval's supporters fortifying/supporting Torval enough, eventually Torval will lose all control systems, except the HQ in Synteini, and/or be removed as a power entirely (due to multiple cycles of failing to expand, losing systems, etc).